# how to upgrade archlinux yaourt install packages?

Tags: google-chrome, archlinux

```
command:yaourt -Ss google-chrome        

archlinuxcn/google-chrome 51.0.2704.106-1 [installed]
An attempt at creating a safer, faster, and more stable browser (Stable Channel)
```

archlinuxcn/google-chrome-dev 53.0.2785.8-1
    An attempt at creating a safer, faster, and more stable browser (Dev Channel)
aur/google-chrome 52.0.2743.82-1 [installed: 51.0.2704.106-1] (Out of Date) (1323) (33.83)
    An attempt at creating a safer, faster, and more stable browser (Stable Channel)
aur/google-chrome-beta 53.0.2785.34-1 (327) (3.09)
    An attempt at creating a safer, faster, and more stable browser (Beta Channel)
aur/google-chrome-dev 54.0.2810.2-1 (594) (3.32)
    An attempt at creating a safer, faster, and more stable browser (Dev Channel)

how to upgrade google-chrome use the yaourt command?

Answer (score 1):

To update an AUR (yaourt) installed package, you have to use the following.

```
yaourt -Syua
```

Also please consider reading the documentation [here](https://archlinux.fr/man/yaourt.8.html).